# jhipster mapstruc relations

Tags: dto, jhipster, mapstruct

Hi I have a model in Jhipster with DTO mapstruct but I can´t correct mapping these relations

```
Person
   -String name
   -...
   Address address

Adress
    -String street
    -String zipCode
```

the generator create the DTO with no relations

```
PersonDTO
   -String name
   -...
   (lack of relation adress)
```

Then I modified my PersonDTO to include Adress like this:

```
PersonDTO
   -String name
   -...
   **-Address address;**
```

when comile the app I have these error:

```
  error: Can't map property "com.kalitron.cxc.web.rest.dto.AddressDTO address"
 to "com.kalitro
    n.cxc.domain.Address address". 
Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "
com.kalitron.cxc.domain.Address map(com.kalitron.cxc.web.rest.dto.AddressDTO value)".
        Person personDTOToPerson(PersonDTO personDTO);
                ^
```

but i dont know how to correct config in the PersonMapper Interface.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

MapStruct does not know how to map the `PersonDto` property "address" of type `AddressDto` into a `Address` to be set into the resulting `Person`. As the error message is saying, declare a method

```
Address addressDtoToAddress(AddressDTO addressDto)
```

on your mapper, applying any configuration through `@Mapping` etc. it may need. The generated `personDTOToPerson()` implementation will then invoke this method for mapping the "address" property.

Comment: There is no way to use an address mapper instead?

Comment: Yes, sure, that method for address mapping can also be declared on another mapper. No need to wrap it in a method on the mapper using it as in your proposed answer. The code generator will detect it and generate an invocation of that method as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Like Gunnar says you must declare a method
And if you want to use the AddressMapper you can inject it:

```
@Inject
AddressMapper addressMapper;
```

And use it in method:

```
Address addressDtoToAddress(AddressDTO addressDto) {
    addressMapper.addressDTOtoAddress(addressDTO);
}
```